# .htaccess to rewrite rules and block file access for specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mini PHP application in a sub-folder called "members", so domain.com/members

In this mini app I have the following in an .htaccess file to redirect URLs such as domain.com/members/categories/some-category or domain.com/members/login etc.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow passthru to existing files/dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/app  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/members/app/assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

# everything else rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*) members/index.php
```

This is allowing my assets folder to load (CSS, JavaScript and images) and also allow any actual file URLs. However, we have a folder of files we now need protected.

So if someone were to go to domain.com/members/files/filename.pdf which would be an actual fileon the server we need this URL to be rewritten into the members/index.php file as we need to check permissions on the file before allowing download.

Whenever I try to remove the following line everything breaks:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^members/index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^members/files/ members/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/app/assets [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ members/index.php [L]
```

Comment: No, in fact it broke everything and nothing was working at all

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser what error did you see?

Comment: It broke all my other rewrites. So domain.com/members/category/5 returned 403 errors and none of the other pages within my app worked - all a 403 error. I was able to use the idea of rewriting all members/files/(.*) URLs to the login page first before the rest of the rewrite rules kicked in though.

Comment: There is no `403` generating directive in these rules. Hope you're not using any other existing rules with this code.` domain.com/members/category/5` should be rewritten to `domain.com/members/index.php ` using above rules.